# Как выровнять блоки div?

Tags: html, css

Сорри за нубский вопрос )

```
<div id="pagination">
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Предыдущая страница') ?></div>
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Следующая страница') ?></div>
</div>

.alignright { text-align: left; }
.alignleft { text-align: right; }
```

Отображается не так как хотелось бы:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А как бы хотелось? )) [Может так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wgmE3/1/):

```
.alignright { float: left; }
.alignleft { float: right; }
```